# what is a better way to process image data for a neural network?

Tags: python, image, neural-network

I made a neural network and it works fine but I tried to use it for image recognition. so I made a program that takes each 3x3 square of an image, make an average of all the color value in it so it becomes 1 tuple of RGB instead of 9 tuple of RGB. then it makes a big array of all these tuple so I can feed it into my neural net. here is the code that transform the image into usable data:

```
from PIL import Image

def norm(lst):
    newtemp = []
    for value in lst:
        if bool(value):
            newtemp.append(value)
    R = []
    G = []
    B = []
    for value in xrange(len(newtemp)):
        R.append(newtemp[value][0])
        G.append(newtemp[value][1])
        B.append(newtemp[value][2])

    R = (sum(R) / len(R))/255.
    G = (sum(G) / len(G))/255.
    B = (sum(B) / len(B))/255.

    return [R,G,B]

def imgConverter(img):
    im = Image.open(img)
    im = im.convert("RGB")
    edge = 3
    width = im.size[0]
    height = im.size[1]
    pix = im.load()
    color = []
    for x in xrange(0, width, edge):
        for y in xrange(0, height, edge):
            xmin = min(x+edge, width)-x
            ymin = min(y+edge, height)-y
            temp = [[] for _ in xrange(edge*edge)]
            for xpos in xrange(0, xmin):
                for ypos in xrange(0, ymin):
                    temp[ymin*ypos+xpos] = pix[x+xpos, y+ypos]
            color.append(norm(temp))
    return color

def datacrunching(color):
    newdata = []
    for RGB in xrange(3):
        for value in xrange(len(color)):
            newdata.append(color[value][RGB])
    return newdata

data = str(datacrunching(imgConverter("cat0.jpg")))
file = open("img_data.txt", "w")
file.write(data)
file.close()
```

it reduce greatly the data to process but even with that, image that are 500x500 will give an array of lenght 83667, which is quite big. feeding it into my neural net as every digit in the array is an input nodes, it wayyyy too slow, is it the way I reduce the image data lenght by crunching every 3x3 square into a 1x1 square the problem or the way I feed it into my neural network? if it is the way I feed it, how should I do it? can someone help please, thanks!

Comment: You may need to read a little bit into `image feature extraction` (Google is your friend); can't give any more advice since that is very dependent on the task at hand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PIL to convert your images into grayscale.

```
from PIL import Image 
image_file = Image.open("convert_image.png") # open colour image
image_file = image_file.convert('1') # convert image to black and white
```

This is much faster than taking an average.

The `image_file` now contains the image as a black and white picture. You can convert this to a numpy matrix and store is as a text file.

---

Training: In the previous step, you should be able to convert your image into a 2D matrix of dimension 500 x 500. This can be flattened to a 1D array of dimension (250000, 1) if you are feeding it as input to an ANN, or can remain 2D input if using a CNN. For images, CNNs are preferred

Comment: I think I didnt explain myself correctly, the program I am showing works fine and is fast, takes second even with image 2000x2000, the problem is when I feed the data into my neural network, the amount of input nodes become immense is too much for my computer. the problem is more on how I feed it into my neural net

Comment: @Tissuebox Edited.